# Memory leak using jquery-ui/datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using these scripts (where jquery-ui[].custom.js is the datepicker plugin):

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script id="formvalidation" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
</script>
```

On this input element (inside a form):

```
<input type="text" name="Date" class="datepicker" />
```

The page loads fine and when I click in the input field the datepicker pops up correctly, but I get a memory leak (in every browser) once a date is selected and the datepicker disappears. This causes that bit of JS to crash or slow down the browser because of a memory leak in jquery-1.5.1.js:

> Line: 1520 Error: Out of memory

When debugging I see the error line is at 2310

```
jQuery.event.remove( elem, type + types );
```

A little context:

```
// Unbind all events for the element
if ( !types || typeof types === "string" && types.charAt(0) === "." ) {
    types = types || "";
    for ( type in events ) {
        jQuery.event.remove( elem, type + types );
    }
    return;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or maybe its a bug in jquery? I'm also using the validation plugin but the same error occurs when I disable it.

[Solved?]
Since I can't post my answer for 8 hours:

Solved the leak by switching to the minimal version of jquery (jquery-1.5.1.min.js & jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js). It appears there is some discrepancy between the min version and the dev version.

Side question: Where would be a good place to bring this up if its not already an issue?

Comment: Does it go away if you use jQuery 1.6?

Comment: No, tried 1.4.1, 1.5.1 AND 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the leak by switching to the minimal version of jquery (jquery-1.5.1.min.js & jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js). It appears there is some discrepancy between the min version and the dev version.

Side question: Where would be a good place to bring this up if its not already an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
```

The construct you have above will pass your function to jQuery as a selector with likely unintended consequences.

Comment: Good try but I tried this and nothing changed. I will add it to my question.

Comment: Did you make the change as I posted, or as is in your question now? It still shows `$(function() {... })` inside `document.ready`, which is wrong. That is the problem isn't not using `document.ready`, the problem is passing a function to jquery.

Comment: Oops I did do it wrong. I switched it to what you have but I still get the same error :S.

Comment: Well that's downright odd. Can you make a jsfiddle with a similified version, which also makes it easy to try different versions of jquery?

Comment: There appears to be no memory leak though, at least that I can tell.

Comment: Are there other elements (possibly non-input) using the class `datepicker` which may not be handled properly by it?

Comment: Nope. I'm going to try just creating a new project and see what happens when I only have those elements.

Comment: Interesting turn of events: switched to the minimal version of jquery (jquery-1.5.1.min.js & jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js) and now it works fine. wtf

Comment: weird. did you poke around at the stack trace in the debugger where it crashed to see if there was anything obviously recursing?